# Why is engine is null or I need to download library

Tags: java, scriptengine

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Triangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript"); 
        Object result = engine.eval("20+3");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I get an exception that engine is null, why?

Comment: You might check this post:  https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/RunOnJDK.md

Comment: "Why?" - See https://openjdk.org/jeps/372.  Note that Nashorn was deprecated in Java 11,